# Incorrect values while normalizing 2d array in C

Tags: c, arrays, random, malloc, 2d

i am trying to normalize an 2D array based on a couple of given equations. The array has being filled with values ranging from 0-255 using the rand() function. The problem is that we i normalize the array, using a couple of given equations, the normalized value is either 0 or 255.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

main ()
{
int x,y;
srand(time(NULL));
int i,j = 0;
int max = NULL;
int min = 255;
long double d;
long double e;

printf("Hello user.\n");
printf("Please enter the horizontal dimension of the array.\n");

scanf("%d", &x);

printf("Please enter the vertical dimension of the array.\n");

scanf("%d", &y);

int MyArray[x][y]; 
float MyArray1[x][y];

int *point = (int *) malloc(x * y * sizeof(int));
float *point1 = (float *) malloc(x * y * sizeof(float));

for (i = 0; i <= (x-1); i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j <= (y-1); j++)
    {
        MyArray[i][j] = (int) (rand() % 256);
        printf("the int is:\n");
        printf("\t %d\n", MyArray[i][j]);

        if (MyArray[i][j] > max )
        {
            max = MyArray[i][j];
        }

        if (MyArray[i][j] < min)
        {
            min = MyArray[i][j];
        }               
    }
}

for (i = 0; i <= (x-1); i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j <= (y-1); j++)
    {
        d = (MyArray[i][j] - min);
        printf("d is: %d\n", d);

        e =( d / (max - min));

        e = (e * 255);
        printf ("e is: %f\n", e);

        MyArray1[i][j] = e;
    }

}

printf("the max is: %d\n", max);
printf("the min is: %d\n", min);

free(point);
free(point1);
}
```

Comment: What is the "normalizing" supposed to produce? Couple of points on technique. `i <= (x-1);` is clearer as `i < x`, and it's better to have the row and column indices the other way round, ie `int MyArray[y][x];`. That might not make much difference here, but it's a good habit to get into, it's important when you are working with 2D image data or string arrays.

Comment: If you provided some example input and output, it would be easier to help.

Comment: always check the returned value (not the parameter value) from scanf(), and family of functions, to assure the input/conversion operation was successful.  Also, the "%d" should probably be "%u" so negative numbers are rejected.

Comment: regarding the calls to malloc():  1) in C, do not cast the returned value 2) always check (!-NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful

Comment: this line: 'int max = NULL;' is wrong, as it is assigning a pointer to an int.  suggest: 'int max = 0;'

Comment: there are only a couple of valid declarations for main() (and one optional declaration)  the valid declarations are: 'int main( int argc, char* argv[] )' and 'int main( void )'   the optional declaration is 'int main()'   Notice that they all have a return type of 'int'

Comment: regarding this king of line: 'printf("d is: %d\n", d);'  'd' is a long double, but '%d' is expecting an int.  Suggest using 'printf("d is" %lf\n", d );  The %llf format should also be used when printing the 'e' variable

Comment: 1) The array 'float MyArray1[x][y]' is set, but never used. Suggest compiling with all warnings enabled, then fix the warnings. 2) It is bad programming practice to differentiate between variable names by only a trailing integer. that makes it too easy to use the wrong name and makes the code much harder for a human to understand 3) point1 is only malloc'd and free'd suggest removing from code  4) point is only malloc'd and free'd  suggest removing from code.

Comment: the min and max are only set to 0 and 255 when there is such a set of numbers returned from rand()%256   In most significant sized array, for instance 10x10 those numbers will be generated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue I can find in your code,

1. `int max = NULL;` is not recommended. use a simple `0` instead.
2. Please do not cast the result of `malloc()`.
3. What is the *point* of having `point` and `point1` here? You can remove them.
4. `printf("d is: %d\n", d);` is wrong. You need to use `%Lf` for a `long double`
5. *Finally*, `printf ("e is: %f\n", e);` is also wrong. You need to use the correct conversion specifier. use `%Lf` for `long double`.

That said, the recommended signature of `main()` is `int main(void)`

Comment: Thanks so much! I new in C so i´m still learning. Once again thanks!

Comment: there is also the invalid return type from main(), which should always be 'int'

Answer (score 0):

here is a version of the posted code.

it cleanly compiles and works

it includes error checking

This version does not contain anything that is not used

nor anything that is not displayed to the user.

Notice that the displayed values (min and max) depend solely on the values returned from rand()%256

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main ()
{
    unsigned int x; // horizontal array dimension
    unsigned int y; // vertical array dimension

    srand(time(NULL));
    int i,j = 0; // loop counters
    int max = 0;
    int min = 255;


    printf("Hello user.\n");
    printf("Please enter the horizontal dimension of the array.\n");

    if( 1 != scanf("%u", &x) )
    { // then scanf failed
        perror( "scanf for x failed" );
        exit( -1 );
    }

    // implied else, scanf successful

    printf("Please enter the vertical dimension of the array.\n");

    if( 1 != scanf("%d", &y) )
    { // then scanf failed
        perror( "scanf for y failed" );
        exit( -1 );
    }

    // implied else, scanf successful

    int MyArray[x][y];

    for (i = 0; i <= (x-1); i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j <= (y-1); j++)
        {
            MyArray[i][j] = (int) (rand() % 256);
            printf("the int is:\n");
            printf("\t %d\n", MyArray[i][j]);

            if (MyArray[i][j] > max )
            {
                max = MyArray[i][j];
            }

            if (MyArray[i][j] < min)
            {
                min = MyArray[i][j];
            }
        }
    }

    printf("the max is: %d\n", max);
    printf("the min is: %d\n", min);
    return(0);
} // end function: main
```